# Am I out of luck if my http client doesn't support gzip decoding?

Tags: support, api-v2

I'm playing with the oauth2 support in v2-beta with an http client that doesn't support gzip decoding. (My client is http spec compliant but can't deal with the non-compliance of the api on this issue).  Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in V2, the API will [honor deflate Accept-Encodings](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression) (it still defaults to GZIP in the absence of an Accept-Encoding).  So, if deflate is an option then you've got a work around.

I'm curious as to what client you're using that doesn't support GZIP?  That's kind of egregious in 2011.

Comment: I'm using the [MarkLogic built-in client](http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/Extension.xml&query="http-get"&category=Extension&function=xdmp:http-get), which unfortunately does not support gzip or deflate.  I agree it's a bit egregious.

Comment: @Eric: You *could* use a proxy that supports GZIP - for example, you could have another application running locally that makes the requests and then have your app just send the request to the local proxy.

Comment: @Eric - hmm, reading over that documentation it looks like under some conditions you'll get a binary object back as the second node.  If that's the case, is there any way to get a hold of zlib or similar in your app?

Comment: Also, I'm glad to here that just plain-old DEFLATE is now supported. Now I can use the API with an unmodified version of Qt, which only provides DEFLATE decompression by default.

Comment: @George - when I try to make a request via an apache proxy, I get the following error: `{"error_id":400,"error_name":"bad_parameter","error_message":"site is required"}`

Comment: @EricBloch: Are you passing `site` as a query string parameter?

Comment: @NathanOsman I am having the same problem, and I *am* passing `site=stackoverflow` in the query string.